# Image preview in SharePoint form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I have two lists,

- Images collection,
- Employees

In the employees list, there's a lookup field that reads data from image collections list

In employees new form list, I would like to show images preview when an item selected from the image collection look up field!

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Hey, Fabio, what kind of restrictions do you have for this? Are you allowed to use Javascript. modify the form with InfoPath, or use webparts in the `Default New Form` and the `Default Edit Form`? Is the list with images strictly a `list` or is it an `assets library`?

Comment: Yes I am allowed to use just with default forms